# Stop position:absolute element causing ancestor to scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css, overflow

How can I keep elements from scrolling horizontally, when a descendant is positioned off the edge of the screen?

I have a [round slider](http://roundsliderui.com/) on the right side of the window, and when the handle is at the edge, it is causing the container element to scroll

[image: highlighting two of the container elements]

Relevant html:

```
<div id="mainScreen">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="round_sliders">
            <div id="leftSlider"></div>
            <div class="flex_spacer"></div>
            <div id="rightSlider"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="loremIpsum">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.round_sliders {
    display: flex;
}
#leftSlider, #rightSlider {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.flex_spacer {
    flex: 1 1 0px;
}
```

I have tried adding `overflow-x: hidden` to `#rightSlider`, and most of its ancestors, but it always cuts off the slider thumb and/or adds vertical scrollbars, while still allowing the element to be scrolled to the right

Edit: [Example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/MalikDrako/pen/mPEmqJ)

Comment: Create a [mcve] and I'll solve it. Here or in jsfiddle. Your aproach was right, but you probably didn't apply it properly.

Comment: Added a codepen link in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
body, #mainScreen {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

That's it. :)

Comment: That works for the example, but I guess it wasnt complete enough - my full version still scrolls, although it is harder to make it happen. It is much better on mobile, but I saw it happen once or twice. I updated the example to be closer to my full version and it happens again.

Comment: That means you have other elements in page that overflow body. My suggestion is to discover them and fix it locally. However, I updated answer with a general fix. Another possible reason might be if you have a stronger selector for overflow rule on that element. Inspect and make sure it applies.

Comment: I have already closed my computer. If you don't sort it out I'll have a look in the morning.

Comment: I ran `$("*").css("border", "1px solid red")` and dont see anything besides the slider thumb that overflow. When I move the slider, it does scroll back to the left. After switching to a full circle slider with a 140deg clamp, I am unable to reproduce the scroll, even though it overflows further.